# DOMDocument and UL tages

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Folks, I'm trying to parse a HTML string and add a `CDATA` tag around any `p` tags, so `<p>something</p>` would end up being `<p><!CDATA[<p>blah</p>]]</p>`. This does what I want in that respect:

```
$html_str = '<p><strong>blah blah blah</strong></p><ul><li>blah blah blah</li><li>blah blah blah</li><li>blah blah blah</li></ul><p>blah blah blah</p>';    
$domdoc = new DOMDocument();                                    
$domdoc->loadHTML($html_str);

foreach( $domdoc->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode ) {
    $cdata = $domdoc->createCDATASection('<p>'. $pnode->nodeValue .'</p>');
    $pnode->replaceChild($cdata, $pnode->childNodes->item(0));
}
echo $domdoc->saveXML();
```

The problem is there are some `ul` tags in the string that are not within `p` tags and I need to do the same thing with those; they need to be surrounded by `CDATA` within a `p` tag, like `<p><!CDATA[<ul>blah</ul>]]</p>`.

I was hoping that I could just go through the string first and add a `p` tag in front of any `ul` and then just use the same above on a 2nd pass to get all the `p` tags to be within a `CDATA`, for example:

```
$html_str = '<p><strong>blah blah blah</strong></p><ul><li>blah blah blah</li><li>blah blah blah</li><li>blah blah blah</li></ul><p>blah blah blah</p>';    
$domdoc = new DOMDocument();                                    
$domdoc->loadHTML($html_str);

foreach( $domdoc->getElementsByTagName("ul") as $ulnode ) { 
    $cdata = $domdoc->createElement("p",$ulnode->nodeValue);
    $domdoc->replaceChild($cdata,$ulnode);
}

foreach( $domdoc->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode ) {
    $cdata = $domdoc->createCDATASection('<p>'. $pnode->nodeValue .'</p>');
    $pnode->replaceChild($cdata, $pnode->childNodes->item(0));
}
echo $domdoc->saveXML();
```

Obviously this didn't work, I ended up with just the content of the `li` items. Can I not do 2 passes like that or is it because the `ul` is a parent with children or something?

What I'm trying to end up with is this:

```
<p><!CDATA[<p><strong>blah blah blah</strong></p>]]></p>
<p><!CDATA[<ul><li>blah blah blah</li><li>blah blah blah</li><li>blah blah blah</li></ul>]]></p>
<p><!CDATA[<p>blah blah blah</p>]]></p>
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CDATA tags, but it looks to me like you have one too many closing brackets on them (`]`).

Comment: Do you mean you may have some `ul` tags within `p`?

Answer (score 0):

First off all, you are trying to mix XML concepts with HTML, as `<![CDATA[]]>` is not a valid HTML construct. So, I think it's best to treat everything as XML. However, this mandates that your HTML fragment must be valid XML.

Then, since your HTML fragment does not have a root element, we use a [`DOMDocumentFragment`](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocumentfragment.php) (via [`DOMDocument::createDocumentFragment`](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.createdocumentfragment.php)) to import the rootless fragment.

Then, we loop through the existing `<p>` elements first, of course, because otherwise we would loop through the `<p>` elements that we added, as well. Afterwards we loop through the existing `<ul>` elements.

As you noticed, `DOMElement->nodeValue` [will merely give you the `textContent` of a node](http://php.net/manual/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue). So, instead, we use [`DOMDocument::saveXML( DOMNode $node )`](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.savexml.php) to insert the XML string into the CDATA sections.

Lastly, we wrap our CDATA sections in newly created `<p>` elements.

To wrap it all up, this is how you get your desired output:

```php
$html_str = '<p><strong>blah blah blah</strong></p><ul><li>blah blah blah</li><li>blah blah blah</li><li>blah blah blah</li></ul><p>blah blah blah</p>';

$domdoc = new DOMDocument();

$domfrag = $domdoc->createDocumentFragment();
$domfrag->appendXML($html_str);

$domdoc->appendChild($domfrag);

foreach($domdoc->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode) {
    $cdata = $domdoc->createCDATASection($domdoc->saveXML($pnode));
    $newPnode = $domdoc->createElement("p");
    $newPnode->appendChild($cdata);
    $pnode->parentNode->replaceChild($newPnode, $pnode);
}

foreach($domdoc->getElementsByTagName("ul") as $ulnode) {
    $cdata = $domdoc->createCDATASection($domdoc->saveXML($ulnode));
    $newPnode = $domdoc->createElement("p");
    $newPnode->appendChild($cdata);
    $ulnode->parentNode->replaceChild($newPnode, $ulnode);
}

/**
 * unfortunately, LIBXML_NOXMLDECL is not supported
 * so $domdoc->saveXML( null, LIBXML_NOXMLDECL ) does not work
 * @see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50989
 */
echo $domdoc->saveXML();

/**
 * so, to drop the <?xml declaration line, you could do the following:
 */
foreach($domdoc->childNodes as $node) {
  echo $domdoc->saveXML($node) . PHP_EOL; // PHP_EOL is optional
}
```

<sup>You can [view this example online](https://3v4l.org/DChZ9).</sup>